# Apache - VirtualDocumentRoot - Subdirectory for whole third-level-domain even with dots in URL

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, subdomain

```
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.mysite.info
    ServerName mysite.info
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/%-3/builds"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace>
            Require all granted
            Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I'm trying to configure apache so that every Jenkins' job has it's own private third level domain. This configuration works well when I access **myproject**.mysite.info and apache returns me /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/**myproject**

Now I would like to have two versions for myproject (alpha, beta) so I would like to call my Jenkins' jobs alpha.myproject and beta.myproject

Doing this way the problem is that alpha.**myproject**.mysite.info will redirect to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/**myproject** anyways becouse myproject will be the third element from the right as specified by the %-3.

It's possible to have something like %--3 so that it takes the third element from right and all preceding parts ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could do:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/%-4.0.%-3/builds"
```

Comment: Will that still handle `foo.mysite.info`?

Comment: I get AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

Comment: Ops, have sense. Look [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html), the dot mean something, should work in the way that I edited the answer now. If not work, you can read the link below and play with the syntax, they have good examples there even one with dot in the document root path. Hope it help.